# Toggle Navigation Overlapping issue

Tags: jquery

How can we achieve "Try Now" button animation to right and back again that will not overlap toggle navigation in responsive screen?

The condition is when we scroll down the page, the #panal div should be hide, that I already did, but when we moves up, it should show the Toggel Button & open the Navigation Panel only OnClick that I also did, but in that case Try Now button animation having issue. So, how can we resolve it?

http://testurproject.tk/deveod/EOD-New/home-sme.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var isMobile = "no";
if (/Android|webOS|iPad|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
isMobile = "yes"
}
if (isMobile == "no") {
var btn_ffLife = !1;
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
if (!btn_ffLife) {
$(".main-intro > .intro > .header-left-list .free-for-life").animate({
right: "32%"
}, 500);
btn_ffLife = !0
} else {
$(".main-intro > .intro > .header-left-list .free-for-life").animate({
right: "10%"
}, 800);
btn_ffLife = !1
}
});
$('body').scrollspy({
target: "header",
offset: 50
})
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 375) {
$("body").addClass("darkHeader");
$(".main-intro > .intro > .header-left-list .free-for-life").animate({
right: "10%"
}, 800)
} else {
$("body").removeClass("darkHeader");
$("#panel").css('display', 'none')
}
})
} else if (isMobile == "yes") {
$(".free-for-life2 img").css('width', '30%');
$(".free-for-life2").css('display', 'block')
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved now.  Finally I used cssText property to resolve the issue.